# gcc: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, undefined-reference

I would like to compile this.

**program.c**

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

int main(){
    int i = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,300,300);
}
```

Running this

```
gcc -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c
```

gives error

```
/tmp/ccxMLBme.o: In function `main':
program.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `avpicture_get_size'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, avpicture_get_size is defined. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

> However, avpicture_get_size is defined.

No, as the header  (`<libavcodec/avcodec.h>`)  just **declares** it.

The **definition** is in the library itself.

So you might like to add the linker option to link `libavcodec` when invoking gcc:

```
-lavcodec
```

---

Please also note that libraries need to be specified on the command line **after** the files needing them:

```
gcc -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c -lavcodec
```

**Not** like this:

```
gcc -lavcodec -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c
```

---

Referring to *[Wyzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226975/wyzard)*'s comment, the complete command might look like this:

```
gcc -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c -L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib -lavcodec
```

For libraries not stored in the linkers standard location the option `-L` specifies an additional search path to lookup libraries specified using the `-l` option, that is `libavcodec.x.y.z` in this case.

---

For a detailed reference on GCC's linker option, [please read here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Comment: And probably something like `-L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib` in this case, since ffmpeg is in the user's home directory rather than installed to system directories.

Comment: Hi alk. Running 'gcc -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c -lavcodes' gave me '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavcodes
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status'

Comment: Hi Wyzard. Running 'gcc -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c -L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib' gave me the exact same error 'program.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `avpicture_get_size'
'

Comment: Thanks! Running 'gcc -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c -L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib -lavcodec' gives 6 undefined reference errors. Some of the methods are from libavcodec and the others are from libavutil. So I added -lavutil at the end of the command and it compiled.

Comment: This paragraph "Please also note that libraries need to be specified on the command line after the files needing them" saved my day, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't GCC be able to find libraries automatically by itself? Do we need to specify lib names when invoking make as well?

Comment: For me, the hint about the order of the parameters was what solved my problem. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 12):

Are you mixing C and C++?  One issue that can occur is that the declarations in the `.h` file for a `.c` file need to be surrounded by:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {                 // Make sure we have C-declarations in C++ programs
#endif
```

and:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
#endif
```

Note:  if unable / unwilling to modify the `.h` file(s) in question, you can surround their inclusion with `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" {
#include <abc.h>
} //extern
```

Comment: Critical step, this. Although it didn't appear to be the original poster's problem, this must be considered in general.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement, I put this in because, while the OP provided a file with a .c extension, the "C++" tag has been set.