# c++ compilation error- undefined reference

Tags: c++, octave, scilab

My cpp file has `Scilab` and `Octave` header files. I'm trying to compile using this command

```
g++ -l:/usr/lib/scilab/libscilab.so -L/usr/lib/scilab -L/usr/lib/scilab -I/usr/include/octave-3.8.1 -I/usr/include/octave-3.8.1/octave -I/usr/include/scilab s_o_test_v4.cpp -o s_o_test_v4
```

I get the following error

```
s_o_test_v4.cpp:(.text+0x5f4): undefined reference to `pvApiCtx'
s_o_test_v4.cpp:(.text+0x5ff): undefined reference to `isVarMatrixType'
s_o_test_v4.cpp:(.text+0x61a): undefined reference to `pvApiCtx'
s_o_test_v4.cpp:(.text+0x644): undefined reference to `getMatrixOfDouble'
s_o_test_v4.cpp:(.text+0x743): undefined reference to `string_vector::c_str_vec() const'
s_o_test_v4.cpp:(.text+0x755): undefined reference to `octave_main'
s_o_test_v4.cpp:(.text+0x7a2): undefined reference to `octave_value::octave_value(double)'
s_o_test_v4.cpp:(.text+0x847): undefined reference to `feval(std::string const&, octave_value_list const&, int)'
s_o_test_v4.cpp:(.text+0x8a3): undefined reference to `pvApiCtx'
```

Both Scilab and Octave functions show error. Should I include or remove something from my compile command?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ordering of your make command is wrong, see also
[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426574/gcc-undefined-reference-to):

> Please also note that libraries need to be specified on the command
>   line after the files needing them

That would make your command:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/octave-3.8.1 -I/usr/include/octave-3.8.1/octave -I/usr/include/scilab s_o_test_v4.cpp -o s_o_test_v4 -l:/usr/lib/scilab/libscilab.so -L/usr/lib/scilab -L/usr/lib/scilab
```