# "undefined reference" error after adding function to a C project

Tags: c, perl

I've added a new function `wiringPiVersion()` to [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com), but after I build and install the shared library, when I attempt to compile a small C program around it, I get:

wpi_ver.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `wiringPiVersion'

However, when I include it in an XS based Perl module, all works well. I don't know enough about C to figure out what's going wrong here, and I've been searching for the better part of two hours trying different things to no avail.

Here's my small C program to test the new function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

int main (){
    char * ver = wiringPiVersion();
    printf("wiringPi version: %s\n", ver);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation that throws the error:

```
gcc -o ver wpi_ver.c -lwiringPi
```

The addition to wiringPi's header file:

```
extern char * wiringPiVersion(void);
```

The wiringPi's .c file addition:

```
#define WPI_VERSION "2.36"

char * wiringPiVersion(void){
    return WPI_VERSION;
}
```

In my Perl module's XS file, I have:

```
char *
wiringPiVersion()
```

...and my Perl module's Makefile.PL

```
LIBS => ['-lwiringPi'],
```

...and after re-installing the Perl module, I can access the function without any issues in a test script.

I'm hoping this is something simple I'm overlooking which someone may be able to point out. My question is, how do I rectify this?

Comment: what does `ldd ver` show?

Comment: Is it for sure that `#include <wiringPi.h>` draws the right file? Can you test to add declaration `char * wiringPiVersion(void);` right in front of your function `main`?

Comment: @ysth `ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.19-18+deb8u4) 2.19`

Comment: @ysth adding the declaration where you stated results in the same error, before and after commenting out the header include line

Comment: I meant running ldd on your test program

Comment: @ysth the app never gets compiled into an executable

Comment: Also, moving the c file into the directory where the modified header is and changing to `#include "wiringPi.h"` doesn't help either

Comment: and `-lwiringPi` draws the binary which you compiled *after* you added function `wiringPiVersion()`, for sure?

Comment: well, there's only one on my system, and I verified that it was updated, and to boot, my Perl XS picks it up fine

Comment: "actually it's a `#define" what is actually a #define? Please post real unedited code that is known to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @StephanLechner I'm wrong... if I use `-L /usr/local/lib` where the updated `.so` is, it works! The only other .so is in the wiringPi compilation directory that's far away from where I'm compiling. I wouldn't think that one would be included. So what you mentioned led to the answer (adding the full library path to the compilation command)

Comment: @n.m. I apologize. Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turned out that there were two `.so` files generated when I rebuilt wiringPi... one in the wiringPi's build directory way under my home directory, and the other in `/usr/local/lib`.

After a tip in comments, I added the library path explicitly:

```
gcc -o ver wpi_ver.c -L/usr/local/lib -lwiringPi
```

...and it all fell together and works as expected:

```
$ ./ver
wiringPi version: 2.36
```

Note: I have sent Gordon the patch in hopes it gets included in the next wiringPi cut.

Update: I received an email back from Gordon and he stated that currently, only the `gpio` application has the ability to report the version, so he advised that he's going to add something similar to my patch in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

Although already solved, I added this answer to show what gave me the hint.
Error message "undefined reference" points to a linker error (cf. [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22426590/2630032)), so its about checking if the correct library is drawn.