# I downloaded libasound2-dev, but I can't find source file

Tags: linux, alsa, libasound

I'm using Linux OS (Ubuntu) and I need some recording file from mic. I typed `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev`.
Then, I can find header file in `/usr/include/alsa` , but I can't find c file.
I think this is the problem of "**undefined reference** to '`snd_pcm_open`'".
What can I do?

Comment: apt-get install on a dev package installs binaries and headers, not the C code. You will need source code separately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc: undefined reference to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426574/gcc-undefined-reference-to)

Comment: You have to link to the alsa library on the command line, I think it is `-lasound`

Comment: Yes, "undefined reference" almost always refers to a compiled subroutine, it could even be in the same program, not a piece of source code.  Probably a library, maybe another program you compile at the same time.  The /opt/vc stuff on a Raspberrry Pi and rtlsdr are infamous for this, your makefile needs to compile several programs besides what you're working on at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

I you want the source code of a libasound2-dev, use the commande

```
apt-get source libasound2-dev
```

You might need to install dpkg-dev package.

Comment: That error message does not refer to any source file.